# terraform get .json from different repository

Tags: terraform, repository, bitbucket

I'm looking for help for one issue that I have.

context:
I have two repositories, one have the apps configuration and the module.

Second repository has the DR project which has disaster recovery in terraform.

Repo1:

```
├── apps
│   └── jira_config.tfvars.json
└── modules
    ├── alb
    │   └── alb.tf
    ├── bitbucket
    │   └── bitbucket.tf
    ├── confluence
    │   └── confluence.tf
    ├── jira
    │   └── jira.tf
    ├── rds
    │   └── rds.tf
    └── rds-group
        └── rds-group.tf
```

Repo2:

```
├── DEV
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── providers.tf
```

What I want to achieve is when I run the terraform from my directory (Repo2), which contains the main.tf ( it has variables declared, also it points the module to Repo1 ) somehow when I terraform init, so it goes to Repo1 and gets apps/jira_config.tfvars.json and saves it as external variables.

Right now I'm accesing to Repo1 to get module using:

```
module "alb" { 
              source = "git::bitbucketRepo1//modules/alb?ref=feature/DR"
```

I was trying to get the variables from Repo1/apps/jira_config.tfvars.json by using:

```
locals {
  external_var = jsondecode(file("git::bitbucketRepo1//apps/jira_config.tfvars.json?ref=feature/DR"))
}
```

The thing is that I couldn't make it work.

Is there any way to achieve this? Should I do it in different way?

My goal is to have Repo2 untouchable and all modifications needs to be made on Repo1, so when I run DR I don't need to worry about outdated/non-updated data.

The workflow that I would like to achieve, more or less, will be:

> terraform init: initialize, which will download the modules and the
> configuration for the apps (jira_config.tfvars.json)
>
> When it downloads the jira_config.tfvars.json I expect to have some
> sort of external variables or a .tfvar.json, basically some source of
> these variables inside Repo2.

One solution that I found is to clone the file whenever I'm about to do DR, but maybe that's not the best solution.

Thanks